# How to avoid DAG generation during task run

Tags: airflow

We have an Airflow python script which read configuration files and then generate > 100 DAGs dynamically. When running the script in Airflow 2.4.1, from the task run log, we notice that Airflow is trying to *parse our python script for every task run*.
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.4.1/airflow/task/task_runner/standard_task_runner.py#L91-L97

Is there any way to make Airflow deserialize DAGs from DBs instead?

Answer (score 0):

just found out that it is an expected behavior
https://medium.com/apache-airflow/airflows-magic-loop-ec424b05b629
https://medium.com/apache-airflow/magic-loop-in-airflow-reloaded-3e1bd8fb6671

but the Python script may use parsing context to load the respective DAG only
https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/25161